# Lagrange multipliers to find maximum and minimum

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

> Use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and minimum values of the function $f(x, y, z) = x - y +z$ on the sphere $x^2 + y^2 +z^2$.

Since gradient vectors have have $x$ to the power of 1 or less does this mean there is only one point?

So far I have this:
$$
1 = \lambda (2x) \\
-1 = \lambda (2y) \\
1 = \lambda (2z) \\
x^2 y^2 +z^2 -1 =0
$$

Hence I only got the point $(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}, \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt3} , \dfrac{1}{\sqrt3} )$.

Comment: You haven't described a sphere, presumably you meant $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$ for some $r$? Also, you should have a $\lambda$ in there which should give two solutions.

Comment: Yes added that .. r=1. How would that give 2 solutions, could you provide some working to help me understand?

Comment: There is another solution, multiply through by $-1$.

Comment: When you took the square root did you include both + and -?

Comment: That was the mistake.